# How to access windows shared directory for music files?

Tags: ipad, music, wifi

I would like to access music files on windows from my iPad.

Is it possible? I really don't think it is a good idea to transfer music files to my ipad since I use ipad at home anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using iTunes on Windows, I think you can just use playlist sharing?

If you're looking to access a directory that's shared from Windows, you'll need to find a utility for your iPad that supports Samba (SMB), as that's the protocol in use for file sharing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Two apps designed for iPhone, but can run on iPad:

1. SMB Lite - free, but file size limited
2. SMB Music - paid